# Passing user authentication from the "Jira User Server" to Artifactory?

Tags: jira, artifactory, atlassian-crowd

Is it possible to pass user authentication from the "Jira User Server" (NOT Crowd) to Artifactory? I Know that Artifactory Pro can communicate with a Crowd Server ... but I couldn't get Artifactory to work with the "Jira User Server"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Artifactory 3.2.x allows you to connect to Jira User Server (you dont need Crowd Server) and login in Artifactory with your Jira Account.

Many Thanks to JFrog

Comment: Removing accepted answers way after you have accepted them is quite poor form on SO. You could add a comment to the accepted answer telling everyone about the new solutions

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen anything which would allow you to use the JIRA user server to serve Artifactory, but I do think that your requirement should make you look at a dedicated user directory service.

LDAP and Active Directory are common user directory tools and are supported by many services and web applications. In our company it is now a requirement that a web application support LDAP to be considered at all.

Although you probably only see a use for Artifactory and JIRA now, your use case can end up much more complex when you want to add (for example) a Git repository or Sharepoint directories. If you take the time to configure a standard user directory now, adding these services later is much simpler.

If you operate in a primarily Windows-based environment, Active Directory is bundled with Windows Server and is probably already used for something. If you're Unix-based, OpenLDAP is relatively easy to set up and manage, and has reasonable documentation.

As an aside, we initially went with Crowd as our user directory because of its ease of use, but since then we've been forced to move to LDAP to integrate with a variety of other systems. Looking back now, it would have been much easier to go straight to LDAP while the number of systems we had was small.

Comment: hm .. the problem is .. we have only UNIX (Ubuntu) based environments ... and still don't have any central user directory ... onle the JIRA User Server is playing such a role ...

Comment: That (handily) rules out the AD option. We too are primarily Ubuntu-based, and have had a positive experience with OpenLDAP. There are good installation and setup documents available: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openldap-server.html being (probably) the most comprehensive. OpenLDAP can be a little intimidating, but if you stick with the standard layout (e.g. ou=People,dc=yourcompany,dc=co,dc=uk or something similar) it's fairly easy to test and get integrated with JIRA.

Comment: Plus, if you get stuck there's great support on forums, here and on ServerFault!